# Tinymce plugin executing based on how many clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tinymce

We added a custom image uploading code to the tinymce plugin. 
It works like this: click on image icon in the tinymce toolbar, the popup appears with uploaded images and we can select the image from the popup by double clicking on it.

**The problem is:** when we select a image first time it loads one image, but when we process same procedure without refreshing the page second time it loads 2 images, on 3rd time it loads 3 images.

```
editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<img src=' + i + '>');
```

it executes upon the clicking time of mouse like 1,2,etc. increased
so I didn't understand what is the solution for this.

Here is the plugin code:

```
tinymce.PluginManager.add('imggallery', function(editor) {
    editor.addCommand('Insert Image', function() {
        $("#myModal2").modal('toggle');
        $(".theme").dblclick(function(){
            var i = $(this).attr('src');

        $('<img src=' + i + '>').appendTo(editor.getBody());
        //editor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, '<img src=' + i + '>');

        //$("#myModal2").modal('toggle');
        $(".close").click();


        });

    });

    editor.addButton('imggallery', {
        icon: 'image',
        tooltip: 'Insert Image',
        cmd: 'Insert Image'
    });


});
```